# How to bind server generated html data into knockout model attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mvvm, knockout.js

I want to bind back server generated html into knockout model. Is there any manner to do it?

```
<table>
    <tr data-bind="with: dataList">
        <td data-bind="text: Name">
            Name
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Text">
            Text
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="with: dataList">
        <td data-bind="text: Name">
            Name2
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Text">
            Text2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Stuff like this...

Answer (score 0):

The dataList property of the object you bound to view will contain all the data you are expecting.

You should use [ko.mapping.toJS()](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to convert an observable view model to a raw view model.

Comment: How does your answer relate to my answer? I want ot turn my server generated html data into knockout model, if that's exactly what you meant, explain me how can your answer be related to my question.